# Provide dependency for C++ headers in meson.build

Tags: c++, build, meson-build

I have a class template defined in a header file that employs a statically linked library, e.g.:

```
// header.hpp file
#include "lib.h"

template <typename T>
class C {
  // ...
};
```

This header is included by multiple source files listed in a `meson.build` file. However, I'm unable to find a way to state that this header depends on the `lib` library.

Here's roughly how my meson.build file look right now:

```
headers = [
  'header.hpp',
]

src = files(
  'source.cpp', # includes header.hpp
)

executable('a.out',
  include_directories : '.',
  sources : src,
  dependencies : [
    lib_dep, # the one that header.hpp depends on
  ],
)
```

Meson's `install_headers` function would probably do the trick, but I do not want to save my headers in a system directory. Another way I'm imagining is using `pkgconfig.generate` to wrap the headers I need, but that also seems a lot more complex than declaring a dependency for source files.

What's the correct way to state that a header depends on something in meson?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, there are two things you are trying to achieve here:

1. You want to avoid adding the header and the library separately to every target.
2. You want all targets to be rebuilt if the header file changes

If so, I think `declare_dependency()` will work.

```
headers = [
  'header.hpp',
]

src = files(
  'source.cpp', # includes header.hpp
)

bundled_lib_dep = declare_dependency(
    sources : headers,
    link_with : [lib_dep],
)

executable('a.out',
  include_directories : '.',
  sources : src,
  dependencies : [
    bundled_lib_dep,
  ],
)
```